# Why is the code coverage value of fastlane xcov different from Xcode's value for the same scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-coverage, fastlane

When I run my tests inside Xcode the code coverage is 10.3%. When running `fastlane run xcov` for the same scheme the code coverage is 17.17%. The xcov html file shows the same files with the same coverage percentages, only the total coverage is incorrect. How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and it turned out that the Xcode versions were not the same. I updated Fastlane's Xcode version to the one I'm using locally and the coverage is the same